# O365 Gear Icon DropDown Menu Edit or How to get to Permission Faster

Tags: permissions

Our company just migrated to O365 and as I am trying to give people permissions and take away permissions, found out that our Gear Icon does not have 'Permission' option available.

It is taking an extra step of gear icon -> site settings -> permissions.

Which is okay but if there is a quick fix, I would love to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to navigate to site permissions in SharePoint in office 365. Which are as below:

1. Hit the url in browser in below format:

   `siteUrl/_layouts/user.aspx`
2. Click on Gear Icon --> Site settings --> Site permissions.
3. Go to Site Contents --> Site settings --> Site permissions.

To quickly access the site permissions page, I think you can use the first approach.

Comment: I really want to give you the upvote but I don't have 15+ reputations yet. Thank you for the brilliant workaround!!! first approach saves me lot of time!

Comment: That's fine. You can always come and upvote when you will have sufficient reputation.